# Using WriteFile to fill up a cluster

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to use Writefile to fill up then end of every file until it reaches the end of its last cluster. Then I want to delete what I wrote and repeat the process(attempting to get rid data that might have been there).

 I have a 2 issues:

1. WriteFile gives me an error: *ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER*
2. Depending on the type of file, `WriteFile()` gives me different results

So for the first issue I realized that the parameter *nNumberOfBytesToWrite* in the `WriteFile()` has to be a multiple of bytes per sector(my case is 512 bytes). Is this a limitation of the function or am I doing something wrong? 
In my second issue, I'm using two dummy files(.txt and .html) on an external hard drive to write random data to. In the case of the *.txt* file, the data is written to the end of the file which is what I need. However, the *.html* file just writes to the beginning of the file and replaces any data that was already there.

 Here are some code snippets relevant to my issue:

```
hFile = CreateFile(result,          
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE |FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,  
                   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                   0,                           
                   OPEN_EXISTING,                    
                   FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                   0);                          

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
}



DWORD dwBytesWritten;
char * wfileBuff = new char[512];
memset (wfileBuff,'0',512);

returnz = SetFilePointer(hFile, 0,NULL,FILE_END);
    if(returnz ==0){
        cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<endl;
};


LockFile(hFile, returnz, 0, 512, 0) 

returnz =WriteFile(hFile, wfileBuff, 512, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
if(returnz ==0){
            cout<<"Error: "<<GetLastError()<<endl;
}

UnlockFile(hFile, returnz, 0, 512, 0);

cout<<dwBytesWritten<<endl<<endl;
```

I am using static numbers at the moment just to test out the functions. 
Is there anyway I can always write to the the end of the file no matter what type of file? I also tried `SetFilePointer(hFile, 0,(fileSize - slackSpace + 1),FILE_BEGIN);` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to heed the information in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx) concerning `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. Specifically this section:

> As previously discussed, an application must meet certain requirements
>   when working with files opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. The
>   following specifics apply:
>
> - File access sizes, including the optional file offset in the OVERLAPPED structure, if specified, must be for a number of bytes that
>     is an integer multiple of the volume sector size. For example, if the
>     sector size is 512 bytes, an application can request reads and writes
>     of 512, 1,024, 1,536, or 2,048 bytes, but not of 335, 981, or 7,171
>     bytes.
> - File access buffer addresses for read and write operations should be physical sector-aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory
>     that are integer multiples of the volume's physical sector size.
>     Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.

Comment: Wow, I completely went over that. Thanks! Any idea about my file type issue?

Comment: I don't really believe that. The file extension cannot influence how `WriteFile` works.

Comment: Your right! It's working now. So to delete what I just wrote, would I set the pointer to the end of the file and write empty characters with `WriteFile` or is there a better function to use? Ideally, I would like to free up the space again.

Comment: I don't really follow all of that. If you want to write you use `WriteFile`. There's nothing else. Free up the space again? Free up what space? Anyway, I think I answered your question.

Comment: I want to delete all the characters I just Wrote with `WriteFile` to free up the space I just used.

Comment: OK, use `SetFilePointerEx` to the original file end location, and then call `SetEndOfFile`. Btw, don't make life hard by using `SetFilePointer`. Use `SetFilePointerEx`. Think about dealing with files whose size does not fit into a 32 bit integer.